# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Trial: Can't use load test plugins

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I am currently evaluating Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Trial version, trying to setup a load test for my app. I created a load test plugin to initialize some test data before each test campaign in the web tests data sources.

But when I run the load test with this plugin added to my load test, I get the following error message:

> An activated full version of Visual Studio Ultimate is required to run
>   the load test with a plugin or a virtual user count greater than 250.

My load test is configured to run with a constant user load, and I tried a few values with the same result (1, 2, 250...).

If I remove this plugin and initialize the datasources manually, it works. Is there any limitation about load test plugins usage in the trial version, or is it a bug?

Comment: This is a feature of the trial version that is clearly explained in the message you quoted. It is not a bug.

Comment: I guess I missed the `a plugin or` part in the message... thank you for pointing that out.